# Azure AD B2B Cross tenant access

Tags: azure, b2b

We have 2 Azure AD tenant in different account.
we are connecting them using B2B cross tenant, after doing with B2B setup, we want the user & group present in 1 tenant should get added into another tenant i.e we don't have to send the invite to the user again from the tenant present in another account, rather then it should federate with other tenant and allow to access the application.

Also we want to set the permission at user level.

can anyone suggest, how we can achieve our use case?